# Xpath contains combined does not work

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

```
  <rim:Slot name="sourcePatientInfo">
                     <rim:ValueList>
                       <rim:Value>PID-3|ST-1000^^^&amp;1.3.6.1.4.1.21367.2003.3.9&amp;ISO</rim:Value>
                        <rim:Value>PID-5|Doe^John^^^</rim:Value>
                        <rim:Value>PID-7|999999</rim:Value>
                        <rim:Value>PID-8|M</rim:Value>
                        <rim:Value>PID-11|19999 St^^Metropolis^Il^44130^USA</rim:Value>
                     </rim:ValueList>
```

Hello I am trying to get the data from the value section. I didnt post the entire xml becuase its big but this is the section i get after running this xpath //*[@name='sourcePatientInfo'] . I want to add a contains after this to pull say PID-3 text but my code contains isnt working Code here.

```
./Value[contains(., 'PID-3|')]]
```

Trying to combine them

```
//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo' and ./Value[contains(., 'PID-3|')]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.

1. The element you are trying to select (`rim:Value`) has a namespace prefix of `rim`. This means that using `Value` in your XPath is not going to work because that would try to select `Value` in no namespace.

   If the tool you're using allows you to bind a prefix to a namespace URI, bind it to whatever the namespace URI in your input XML binds `rim` to. Then you can use `rim` (or whatever prefix you bound the namespace URI to) in your XPath.

   If the tool does not allow binding the namespace URI to a prefix, you can use `local-name()` (and ideally `namespace-uri()`).
2. `rim:Value` is a descendant of `rim:Slot` (which has the correct `@name`), not a direct child. This means `./Value` (or `./rim:Value`) is not going to select anything.

   If you know for sure that `rim:Value` is a child of `rim:ValueList`, you could specify it directly. If `rim:ValueList` can vary, but the depth of `rim:Value` is the same, you can use `*`. If none of that is known, you can use `//`.

Here are a few options (with `rim` bound)...

```
//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo']/rim:ValueList/rim:Value[contains(.,'PID-3|')]

//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo']/*/rim:Value[contains(.,'PID-3|')]

//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo']//rim:Value[contains(.,'PID-3|')]
```

If you cannot bind the namespace...

```
//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo']//*[local-name()='Value'][contains(.,'PID-3|')]
```

The example that uses `local-name()` will match any element whose local name is `Value` no matter what namespace it's in. To be more specific in your XPath, you can add `namespace-uri()`...

```
//*[@name='sourcePatientInfo']//*[local-name()='Value' and namespace-uri()='some namespace uri'][contains(.,'PID-3|')]
```

Comment: Yes thank you. That works. Also yes the namespace would be an issue for me because it could change so i used the local which also works.